# Remove the space above content in zendframework layout

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, layout

I have a zend framework layout like this:

```
...
<div id="div1"></div>
<?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
...
```

The problem is a space between `div1` and `content` about 15px.

How can i remove it?

**EDIT:** I use inspect element in chrome, there is a " " (spaces between double quotations) above content that i don't add it.

**EDIT:** Please see below picture, I don't add the selected area.

[image: I don't add the selected area.]

Comment: What is around these two lines? Any other markup plus the CSS used will be useful to assist you.

Comment: I first design it's HTML without space and then move a part of it to `content`, after adding content the space was created.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a Zend Framework issue to me. Check the actual markup and browser parse trees as well as your CSS.

Comment: I use `inspect element` in chrome, there is a `"              "` (spaces between double quotations) above content that i don't add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My content page's encoding was `UTF 8 with BOM`. 
This encoding add a character in the begin of file, and that character cause to those spaces. 
I use encoding `UTF 8 witout BOM`.

Answer (score 0):

try setting a negative bottom margin for your div

http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_margin.asp

Comment: I try `margin`, `pdding` and other `css` properties but not solved.

Comment: empty spaces taht you don't add, check your php code, it has got to be it, make sure your editor deletes extra white-space at the end of each line(Eclipse has such an option) also see this link http://blog.rogeriopvl.com/archives/php-files-closing-the-php-tag-or-not/